# Extract strings from variable, except those in bbcode

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have for example this variable:

```
$variable = "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet [url=http://loremipsum.com]Lorem Ipsum[/url]";
```

My goal is to get just those strings that aren't in [url] bbcode.

For example above: When I want get the "lorem" string, it will select just the first one, omitting the string in the [url]).

How can I do that?

Comment: so you mean you want to search for "lorem" and it should return exactly "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet" omitting the content inside the []?

Comment: Nope, I want just return all of "lorem", omitting the content inside the [url] bbcode.

Comment: So, show us what you tried so far. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the discard technique. For instance, you can use this regex:

```
\[.*?\]|(lorem)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zG1nS3/1)**

[image]

Then, grab the content from the capturing group.

On the other hand, if you want to capture the full strings that are not inside the tags, you could use:

```
\[.*?\]|([\w\s]+)
```